# Can't find old RSpec version after switching from RVM to rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rbenv

A couple of days ago I switched from RVM to rbenv. I now have issues with rspec for a rails project. I'm getting this message:

```
You have already activated rspec-core 3.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.14.8.
```

I tried to do:

```
gem install rspec-core '2.14.8'
```

but then I got this error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '2.14.8' (>= 0) in any repository
```

after which rbenv just uses RSpec 3.0.3.

So the only way now to run the test in my Rails project is to use:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

Is there a way to install a pre-RSpec 3 version of RSpec beside the installed RSpec 3.0.3 so I can again run the test in my Rails project by just typing:

```
rspec spec
```

I'm using Rails 4.1.1.

Comment: hi Dave, I'm using Rails 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The Rails 4 way to run things under bundler and spring is to run scripts in the bin directory. To generate such a script for rspec, install the spring-commands-rspec gem and run `bundle exec spring binstub --all`. If your current directory is the root of your rails project, you can then just type `bin/rspec`.

Side note: RSpec runs the spec directory by default, so you don't need to type `spec`.

To save typing `bin/`, either add your Rails project's bin directory to your PATH in the usual way or use [direnv](https://github.com/zimbatm/direnv).

You probably want rspec-rails, not just RSpec. If so, since you're using Rails 4.1.x, you'll need rspec-rails 2.99, which needs rspec 2.99.x, not 2.14.x. (Documented in [rspec-rails' Changelog](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/Changelog.md).)

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the explanation. I have rspec-rails 2.14.8 already  installed. The problem I have though is that I'm using Rspec version 3.0.3. So I'm getting this error message: You have already activated rspec-core 3.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.14.8. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
 from /Users/acandael/.rben. I guess this has to do with switching from RVM to rbenv. I can't upgrade to Rspec 3 because then a lot of the test for my Rails project brake. So I'm looking for a way to have Rspec 2.14.8 installed besides Rspec 3.0.3

Comment: What I said will allow you to do that. The scripts in bin run code in the environment defined by your Gemfile (ignoring RSpec 3), same as typing `bundle exec whatever`.